# Cordova-plugin-file-transfer FileTransfer download error code 3 - handshake failed in ionic application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

In my ionic application I always get an error when I try to download a pdf document from our server using the cordova file transfer plugin:

### Code Snippet

```
public getDocument(url: string, filePath: string, fileName: string): 
Promise<boolean> {

const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
let headers = this.createHeader();
let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

return this.documentPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fileTransfer.download(url, filePath + fileName, true, requestOptions)
    .then((entry) => {
      resolve(entry.toURL());
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
```

It jumps directly into the catch case and gives the following

### Error

```
JSON.stringify(error)

>> 
"code": 3, 
"source": "https://asd.mysite.de/proxy/bill/app/pdfdocument", 
"target": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/subdomain.domainname.toplevdomain/files/document.pdf" 
"http_status": null, 
"body": null, 
"exception": "Handshake failed"
```

The "source" path is reachable and  and the file is downloadable from other devices. On my phone by now there exists the path "/storage/emulated" and the rest of the path is never created.

This only happens on my Samsung A3 with the latest android version and on a fairly new Huawei phone, but not on other android phones or ios.

Any ideas on why this error might occur?

### This is my running system:

```
cli packages: (D:\Users\...)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.11.0
npm               : 5.3.0
OS                : Windows 7
```

The relevant plugins are set with this version:

```
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.0.19",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.6.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
```

Comment: Error code 3 denotes the connection error. Ensure that your source url is reachable

Comment: @Gandhi the "source" path looks like "https://asd.mysite.de/proxy/bill/app/pdfdocument" and like I mentioned in the OP the file is reachable and downloadable from other devices. The "target" path looks like "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/subdomain.domainname.toplevdomain/files/document.pdf". On my phone by now there exists the path "/storage/emulated" and the rest of the path is never created because of the error I suppose.

Comment: Then it could be a possible permission issue in creating folders. Try out datadirectory to store the file is possible Check this is out - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: @Gandhi what do you mean exactly datadirectory? Also I am sorry, I cannot make sense out of your repo for my project right now. What would you propose I could do with your repo?

Comment: That has the code to download file from your server to the device. You file path can be something like cordova.file.externalDataDirectory+ "FILE_NAME". you gotta use file plugin for this

Comment: yeah, ok, I got it. I tried to use

`if(this.platform.is('android')) 
    {
        this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    }`

but this doesn't work either